# Fixing a Calculation Mistake on p.51 in "Mathematical Analysis I" by Vladimir A. Zorich?

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers

While reading *"Mathematical Analysis I" by Vladimir A. Zorich*. I came across this proof regarding the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ :

Let $X$ and $Y$ be the sets of positive real numbers such that $\forall x \in X\left(x^{2}<2\right)$ $\forall y \in Y\left(2<y^{2}\right) .$ Since $1 \in X$ and $2 \in Y,$ it follows that $X$ and $Y$ are nonempty sets. Further, since $(x<y) \Leftrightarrow\left(x^{2}<y^{2}\right)$ for positive numbers $x$ and $y,$ every element of $X$ is less than every element of $Y .$ By the completeness axiom there exists $s \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x \leq s \leq y$ for all $x \in X$ and all $y \in Y$ We shall show that $s^{2}=2$ If $s^{2}<2,$ then, for example, the number $s+\frac{2-s^{2}}{3 s},$ which is larger than $s,$ would have a square less than $2 .$ Indeed, we know that $1 \in X,$ so that $1^{2} \leq s^{2}<2,$ and $0<\Delta:=2-s^{2} \leq 1 .$ It follows that :

> $$
> \boxed{\left(s+\frac{\Delta}{3 s}\right)^{2}=s^{2}+2 \cdot \frac{\Delta}{3 s}+\left(\frac{\Delta}{3 s}\right)^{2}<s^{2}+3 \cdot \frac{\Delta}{3 s}<s^{2}+3 \cdot \frac{\Delta}{3 s}=s^{2}+\Delta=2}
> $$

The author made a simple mistake during the expansion as seen in the box above. Therefore, I attempt to fix the proof as follow :

Since $1 \leq s^2$ and $\frac{\Delta}{3}<1$ hold, then :
\begin{align*}
\left(s+\frac{\Delta}{3s}\right)^2&=s^2+2\cdot\frac{\Delta}{3}+\left(\frac{\Delta}{3s}\right)^2\\
&\leq s^2+2\cdot\frac{\Delta}{3}+\left(\frac{\Delta}{3}\right)^2\\
&<s^2+2\cdot\frac{\Delta}{3}+\frac{\Delta}{3}\\ 
&= s^2+3\cdot\frac{\Delta}{3}\\
&=s^2+\Delta \\
&= 2
\end{align*}
Hence, $(s+\frac{\Delta}{3s})^2<2$ is true as required.

> Are my steps correct in my attempt to fix this part of the proof?

Comment: Well seems you've corrected it, it is just a typo that the 3 in the expression should be 2.

Comment: I agree looks correct to me too.

Comment: @macton Thank you very much.

Comment: @xXACEXx Thank you very much.

Comment: @xXACEXx Thank you very very much for your edit.

Comment: :-) Cheers!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What year was your edition of Zorich published? A copy of the Russian edition from 2012 is [here](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eeskin/math203/Analiz%201%20(2012).pdf). It has the expansion you write about on the bottom of page number 77 and the calculations there match your correction.

Comment: KCd, I am reading Vladimir A. Zorich "Mathematical Analysis I Second Edition". And this book was translated by Roger Cooke and Octavio Paniagua T.

Comment: KCd, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: I bought a copy of the book from Springer in late July last year.

Comment: I found "Preface to the Sixth Russian Edition" in this book. So, I guess this book was translated from Sixth Russian Edition.

Comment: That link to a Russian version of the book goes to the 6th edition: the first page at the link says Издание шестое and you can throw that into Google Translate to see it means "sixth edition".  So what you found is a printing error in the translation.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate approach:

Worth looking at the concrete equation $x^2 - 2 = 0$ we are dealing with. We know that there are methods to solve this equation. Among them, there is the Newton  approximation (going on the tangent), and the secant method.
In this case, since we want values less than the solution, we use the secant method.

So consider the points on the graph $(s, s^2-2)$ below the horizontal,  axis, and $(2, 2^2 - 2)$ above the horizontal axis. Join them and consider the point of intersection with the horizontal axis $(s', 0)$.
From the picture, we should have $s'> s$, and $s'^2-2 < 0$.
[image: secant method]

Now, a simple calculation gives
$$s' = \frac{2(s+1)}{s+2}$$
Check that
\begin{eqnarray}
s' - s &=& \frac{2-s^2}{s+2}\\
2 - s'^2 &=& \frac{2(2-s^2)}{(s+2)^2}
\end{eqnarray}

$\bf{Added:}$ Pleased to notice  this matches the calculation  in Rudin's Principles (exp 1.1).  The fog is rising..

Comment: orangeskid, Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @tchappy ha: you are very welcome!  Good luck in your study!